# Unable to query a view referenced from a table in a different schema

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

We have `Table1` in `SchemaA`, and a `View1` created in `SchemaB` referencing data from `Table1`. UserOne who created `View1` has role privileges in both `SchemaA` and `SchemaB`.

UserTwo with a different role who was granted `SELECT` privileges for `SchemaB` gets a `SQL compilation error: Failure during expansion of view 'View1': SQL compilation error: Schema 'SchemaA' does not exist or not authorized.` when trying to query `View1`. We do not want UserTwo to have direct access to `SchemaA`.

I assume this is an issue of privileges (`USAGE` for `Schema A`) but we do not have much flexibility on access control. Is there something else we could do?

Answer (score 0):

I think UserTwo is the owner of the view, and the owner of the view doesn't have access to SchemaA. So you should create the view by the UserOne, and grant SELECT on the view to UserTwo. In this case, UserTwo will be able to query the view even without any permission on schemaA.

```
use role accountadmin;

create database gokhan_db;
create schema schemaA;
create table schemaA.table1 (v varchar) as select 'Test';

create schema SchemaB;
create view schemaB.view1 as select * from schemaA.table1; -- owner is accountadmin

create role testing_role;
grant role testing_role to user gokhan; -- my user ;)
grant usage on warehouse gokhan_wh to role testing_role;

grant usage on database gokhan_db to role testing_role;
grant usage on schema gokhan_db.schemaB to role testing_role;
grant select on view gokhan_db.schemaB.view1 to role testing_role;

use role testing_role;
select * from view1; -- works
```